# for next loop will not end, and it willreturn index out of range

Tags: vb.net

i have 5 columns which i have to delete the row that already exist in my databases so that the remaining row that doesnt exist in my database are ready for insert into the database.. but still i have an error of Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index..

the problem is the for next loop will not end even if the lastrow of the datagridview already reach..

i have set the property of allowusertoaddrows to false..

this is my code..

```
Private Sub btnCheck_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click
        Dim rctr, x As Integer

        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=ITS-CODER02\DIBMART; Initial Catalog = HiKLotMgt; User Id= sa; Password = evadkram!@#;")
        con.Open()

        For x = 0 To gridhik.Rows.Count - 1

            cerlotno = gridhik.Item(2, x).Value
            sqlexist = "Select * from tblHikLotMgtDB where CeramicLotNo = '" & cerlotno & "'"
            Dim cmd1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlexist, con)
            Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader

            If rdr.HasRows Then
                MsgBox("Ceramic Lot No: " + cerlotno + " already exists and will be deleted.", vbInformation)

                gridhik.Rows.Remove(gridhik.Rows(x))
                x = x - 1
            End If

            rdr.Close()
        Next
        MsgBox("Ready for Saving....", vbInformation)
    End Sub
```

thanks in advance for those who help.. thanks...

Comment: this is my data Row(0) is cerlotno1 Row(1) is cerlotno(2) row(2) is cerlotno3, row(3) is cerlotno4 and row(4) is cerlotno(5)........ in my database cerlotno 2,3,5 already exist in my database.. so in the datagridview.. i want to delete cerlotno 2,3,5.. that will be the flow... so the remaining output row(0) is cerlotno1 and row(1) is cerlotno 4.. that remaining data are ready for insert in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Say the grid initially has 10 rows, 0-9.
You are removing a grid row within the loop, which means that there are no longer the original 10 rows, so therefore the last row is now (8), and (9) no longer exists; this is why you get your index out of range error.
Refactor your loop so it starts at the last row and winds down ie For x = gridhik.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 step -1